# How do I setup a distribution that contains additional install profiles?

Tags: 9, distributions

Sorry for the fairly long explanation - but its the only way to explain my requirements fully.

I have a Drupal distribution called "Business" and I packaged it as an installation profile and put it in /profiles of my Drupal installation. I also marked it as a distribution which means it is auto-selected during install. But I want this distribution to contain 2 other installation profiles called "Business Standard" and "Business Professional".

I have created these 2 sub install profiles and put them in the /profile folder of my distribution (not the /profile folder of Drupal parent folder). What I want is that "Business Version 4" is shown on the install page (which is the case presently) and then it shows me the 2 sub profiles "Business Standard" and "Business Professional" and allows me to choose which to install. But it doesn't show the 2 sub profiles.

I've also gone the path of trying to put the 2 sub profiles (Business Standard and Business Professioanl) directly inside the /profiles folder of the Drupal installation - and they are correctly shown in the install page - only problem is that the "Standard" Drupal profile is shown as well, which I don't want to be visible. Is there then a way of "hiding the Standard install profile"? Or how can I achieve these requirements please?

Thanks.

Comment: Pls any hints at all on this, guys? Thanks.